# Replacement for bintray for hosting debs of scala project?

Tags: apt, ppa, debian

I have an open source scala project (https://github.com/lucidsoftware/piezo) which currently deploys a deb to an apt repo on bintray. Unfortunately, bintray is [going away in May](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), and I'm looking for a replacement.

The most obvious choice was to set up a PPA. However, that requires compiling completely from source without internet access, which is extraordinarily difficult for an sbt project, because not only do I need to include the sources and compile all of the transitive dependencies, but I need to do that for the build tool (sbt) and its dependencies as well. It doesn't help that I haven't been able to find any examples of how to make a source deb for an sbt-based project.

So is there another free public apt repo I could just upload a binary deb to? I'd also accept advise on how to create a PPA for a scala/sbt project.

Or am I consigned to just uploading a deb to the github release pages?

Comment: I do not see a Ubuntu question here.

Comment: I want to make the package available to easily install on Ubuntu. Is there a better place to ask this?

Comment: Maybe here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/